# Gradle, different versions of direct and transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

Suppose `application` module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.example.http:core:5.1"
    implementation "com.example.common:network:1.0"
}
```

And `http` core third party project buid.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.example.common:network:2.0"
}
```

(so `http`'s .pom has dependency of `network` 2.0 inside)

In this case gradle will choise `network` module of version 2.0 for both `application` and `http` modules.
But how can I make gradle use both versions of `network`: 1.0 as direct `application` and 2.0 as transitive `http` dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique for resolving clashing dependencies called **shadow** jar.

Conviniently enough, there is an [awesome gradle plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/) for building these.

Comment: That will only work if you [relocate packages](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/) and that is not always easy to do.